# I'm trying to implement DMD concept of java.But not getting the output as expected

Tags: java, overriding

```
     class Rectangle extends Tri{
       public void draw() {
         System.out.println("Rectangle");
       }  
     } 

     class Tri {
      public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Triangle");
       }
     }

    class Circle extends Rectangle{
     public void draw() {
      System.out.println("Circle");
      }
     }

    class rect
    {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
      Circle c=new Circle();
      Tri t=new Tri();
      Rectangle r=new Rectangle(); 

      r.draw(); //Rectangle
      r=c;
      r.draw();  //Circle
      t=r;
      t.draw(); // Rectangle expected.But getting Circle as output.
       }
     }
```

In "**t.draw**" where I'm giving reference to "**t=r**", it should display **"Rectangle"** but i'm getting output as **"Circle"**.May be that is because of earlier referencing **r=c**.
But it is still a doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've previously assigned `c` to the variable `r`.

By the time you get to the line `t = r`, `r = c` already ... so now `t = c`.

Why would you create the variable `t` just to assign `r` and `c` to it?  Why not just deal with `r` and `c` directly to make things more clear?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is as expected because you have assigned r = c and then t = r so the object t reference holding is of c i.e. circle. Hence it is printing output as Circle. I hope this explains the behaviour of JAVA.